How to add automated created_at and updated_at columns using alembic?
Like in rails when we create a migration, rails itself add a 2 columns created_at and updated_at and it is automatically updated in the database.
How to do this in python using alembic? Like to automate this whenever we create a model.
Tried creating mixins and it workded, but still we have to add these column manually in migration. It is not like we added a migration and mentioned a model and it creates the created_at and updated_at columns automatically

Mixins should be automagically detected when running with --autogenerate in alembic, do you have a small example that shows that it doesn't work?

Just created a migration to add created_at and updated_at column in existing model. Then i added the mixin to audit values in it but something seems to be missing.
I have called the mixing from db_models like this : class Model(Base, TimeStampMixin):
should be this running automatically or there is some step to call this ?

You have to have TimeStampMixing first, Base needs to be last. The fields needs to be added to the model before you generate the migration if you want them to show up automagically in the migration (the migration is where they show up automagically, not in the model). You generate migrations to match your models, not the other way around.
